# Redirect of HTTP methods

Tags: http, nginx, proxy, reverse

Stackoverflowers,
can someone please advise on the below:

I need to redirect a list of http url methods to another server when they are hit and rest of the site's methods not to be redirected. Can you please advise me how this can be achieved ?
Here's what I mean :

```
base address = https://example.com

<base address>/methods/asyncwebmethods.ashx/JwtTokenLogin
to be redirected to  
<http://bg2-858-lt>/JwtTokenLogin

<base address>/methods/asyncwebmethods.ashx/logout 
to be redirected to 
<http://bg2-858-lt>/JwtTokenLogin

<base address>methods/betting.ashx/updateRegularCartItems
to be redirected to
<http://bg2-858-lt>/updateRegularCartItems
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in many ways.
1. simple jquery to handle the action when login/logout button clicked.
2. In httpd.conf
3. In the servelt you can redirect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response, I was asking more about some server acting like a reverse-proxy(router). If you access https://example.com//methods/asyncwebmethods.ashx/JwtTokenLogin
reverse proxy to redirect it to <http://bg2-858-lt>/JwtTokenLogin

Comment: haa ok.. if it is apache, you can refer here. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: keep in mind, that in http terminology "redirect" has specific meaning (e.g. a 301 or 302 response) which causes the client to make another request.  In the context of request methods, it was (maybe still is) common for browsers if they get a redirect response to POST, to issue a GET to the redirect location (from the Location header).

Comment: Is there a way to have a server for example 192.168.0.5 which acts as a reverse proxy and when reach it to redirects me to https://example.com and when I click on some button in this page (for example login) to redirects me on another page chosen by me ?

Comment: hi, what is the weserver that you are using